# Laravel dosen't connect with Oracle

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using  **[yajra/laravel-oci8](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8)** for Oracle connection with laravel. But I couldn't connected to Oracle, from my client PC to Server.

showing this error:
[image]

I'm using this code in database.php:

```
'oracle' => array(
       'driver' => 'oracle',
       'host' => '192.168.152.189',// this is my server IP
       'port' => '1521',
       'database' => 'ocp',
       'username' => 'ocpl',
       'password' => '123456',
       'charset' => 'AL32UTF8',
       'prefix' => '',
       'port' => 1521
  ),
```

But I'm connected with Sql Developer.
see the Sql-Developer Property: [image]

Comment: The SID in SQL Developer doesn't match the database name in your config.

Comment: Change your database to orcl

Comment: but where i can give the SID. @Mat

Comment: I was tried this 'orcl' as database, but not connected. @Mihai

Comment: You also have 'port' defined twice! I'm not sure what that will do?

Answer (score 0):

problem in this line :                 `'database' => 'ocp' ,`
solve it with :    `'database' => 'orcl' ,`      or

'database' => '192.168.152.189/orcl'

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
'oracle' => array(
       'driver' => 'oracle',
       'tns' => '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.152.189)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))',
       //'host' => '192.168.152.189',// this is my server IP
       //'port' => '1521',
       'database' => '',
       'username' => 'ocpl',
       'password' => '123456',
       'charset' => 'AL32UTF8',
       'prefix' => '',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been posted after almost three year...
but I just use this way to solve this problem

search this command in oracle

```
Select instance_name from v$instance;
```

then paste the value into  'database' setting